# rspec runs the tests in another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading the book Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial, and as instructed I set up my rails app to use rspec for testing.  Whenever I was instructed to, I created new tests, and the tests ran automatically using autotest and spork.  Everything seemed to work fine.  Then I created a second app in order to test some code, but when I ran a couple of tests in my second app with the command:

> $ bundle exec rspec spec/

...the tests for the first app executed.  How can running rspec in one app execute the tests in another app? I cd'ed to another directory, cd'ed back into the second app, and ran the tests again, but the same thing happened.

In an attempt to correct that sad state of affairs, I closed out every window on my computer, and then I restarted my computer.  After my computer rebooted, I opened one Terminal window, cd'ed into the directory for the second app, and once again I issued the command:

> $ bundle exec rspec spec/

Now I get an error that says, "You cannot have more than one Rails::Application (RuntimeError)":

> No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/
>   railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:63:in `inherited': You
>   cannot have more than one 
>   Rails::Application (RuntimeError)

Is there something obvious I'm missing?  The setup was laborious for the first app, and I tried to repeat the same setup for my second app, but I can't get any tests to run.  Both apps have identical Gemfiles.

osx 10.6.7

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that my problem has to do with the name of 
my app--it's test_app.  I created another app and after running through 
the extensive setup, I can now run rspec tests on it.  

In an attempt to get my test_app working, I tried deleting the gemset and reinstalling rails and all the gems, and I closely examined the spec/spec_helper.rb file, but I could never get the tests to work: I kept getting the error:

``inherited': You cannot have more than one Rails::Application (RuntimeError)`

Comment: It's not the app name.  I created another app called test_map, and I set up some simple tests for that app, and they ran without error.  I've deleted the gemset for the troublesome test_app at least ten times and then started over with the setup but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your app test_app.  It's probably something with drb/spork.  Post your spec_helper.rb.  Also, take out the drb option out of spec_helper.rb, comment out the Spork config, copy what is in the prefork block back to the bottom of the spec_helper file (where it used to be).  Run rspec spec without bundle exec.  If that doesn't work, run one test with rspec/spec/some_file.rb.